# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and setting kCVPixelBufferWidthKey & kCVPixelBufferHeightKey

Tags: iphone, ios, video-capture, avcapturesession

I'm trying to capture frames in a specific size from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` by setting `kCVPixelBufferWidthKey` & `kCVPixelBufferHeightKey`.
Problem is the buffer width and height never change, they always come back **852x640**

Here is me code:

```
// Add the video frame output   
    self.videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [videoOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
// Use RGB frames instead of YUV to ease color processing
[videoOutput setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:320.0], (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:320.0], (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA],(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                                              nil]];
 [videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

EDIT: from iOS AVCaptureOutput.h: Currently, the only supported key is kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey.

anyone knows a working method of setting the output buffer width/height ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from iOS AVCaptureOutput.h: `Currently, the only supported key is kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey.`

this sums it up.

Comment: I wish it did work though -- I could really use that too. :-)