# AVCaptureSessionPreset Photo and High Optimization

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have been trying all kinds of settings for the AVCaptureSessionPreset to match my desired output, but I don't seem to be able to get it right.

The Photo preset captures a photo where the resolution is too high, so it takes some time before the image is finished processing.

The High preset is perfect in the sense of performance. The image gets processed and returned almost instantaneously. But the aspect ratio is not right, it is 16:9 compared to the Photo preset which is 4:3.

I have also tried changing the AVCaptureDevice's activeFormat to a lower resolution. But the performance is just not as good as when using the High preset.

Someone with a similar problem from 2014:
[AVCaptureSession preset creates a photo that is too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753227/avcapturesession-preset-creates-a-photo-that-is-too-big)

Comment: Are you capturing still image or video? Can you show what you mean by "it takes some time"? What's your actual code, please?

Comment: Oh I linked to the wrong one, I changed it. I am capturing still images.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you are attempting to perform some kind of time-consuming processing on the large photo data returned from the capture. Don't. It's large! Instead, when you configure the session, ask for a *preview image* at the desired size, and when the capture takes place, obtain the preview image and operate on that.

Comment: Example for iOS 11: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch17p707takeAPicAVFoundation/ch30p966takeAPicAVFoundation/ViewController.swift - look at how we configure and apply the AVCapturePhotoSettings, and how we then extract the preview image by calling `previewCGImageRepresentation`.

Comment: Example for iOS 10 and before (very different): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS10bookexamples/bk2ch17p707takeAPicAVFoundation/ch30p966takeAPicAVFoundation/ViewController.swift Here we arrange to get a `previewPhotoSampleBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can only get the preview image up to 854x640. This person has the sam problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967937/avcapturevideodataoutput-and-setting-kcvpixelbufferwidthkey-kcvpixelbufferheig

Comment: Linked question looks unrelated. — No size requirements in your question. You asked for smaller but correct aspect ratio, I gave it to you.